# Is it possible to play sounds from speakers even when connected to remote media speaker via bluetooth

Tags: android, cordova, bluetooth

Using Cordova and Android (and iOS if possible).

For example, when connected to the vehicle bluetooth and on radio channel, sounds from the app won't be played. Therefore I need to play them via the physical device speakers.

I have tried native audio plugin for Cordova and the Cordova media plugin, both didn't work and sound is not playing since the default station is radio in the vehicle.

Answer (score 0):

Try steps blow:

1. Open Setting App
2. Open Bluetooth Setting page
3. Open paired Bluetooth Device Setting page or Dialog
4. Uncheck the option of Phone Audio

But i don't know how to set this by code

Comment: That is not good since it changes the Bluetooths actual settings which is not needed in this case. It also doesn't work.
I need that sound will be played from the device speaker no matter what - even when connected to headphone or in call